# vertical scrollview not working on fragment xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin

I am working on xamarin android.
I am using the layout inside the LayoutInflater. The scrollview is not scrolled vertically.
My Layout xaml code(Prof_Vehicle.xaml) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout114">
  <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
      <TextView
          android:text="Vehicle Name"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:layout_width="125.5dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />
      <EditText
          android:layout_width="234.0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/EtVehicleName"
          android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="-30dp" />

.....
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my xamarin android code(Prof_Vehicle.cs) is:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Prof_Vehicle, container, false);
...........
return view;
}
```

Could anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the scroll view the parent itself,the outer linear layout is redundant. Then height and width should be match_parent.Then the inner linear layout width should be match_parent and height wrap content.With layout_gravity="center".

```
return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.Prof_Vehicle,container);
```

Try inflating this way,also remember to set these attributes on the layout when re-ordering.

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

Comment: I have rearrange the code like below:
Prof_Vehicle.xaml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
      android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
      ...
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>

Comment: Prof_Vehicle.cs:
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    ...........
return  **LayoutInflater.From(Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.Prof_Vehicle, container**);
}

But it shows error like the below:
**"Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first".**

Comment: Alright make sense, just remember do not inflate a new Layout inflater from context, just use the prior. View view = inflater.Inflate(R.layout.Prof_Vehicle, container, false); Try it exactly this way!

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the delay reply. it's working fine now.